# Apache 2.2: RewriteMap, ProxyPass interpolation and Keep-Alive

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, keep-alive

I have an Apache httpd used as a SSL reverse proxy frontend for a lot of backends.
I compute the name of the backend from the path given by the user.
e.g: `https://myhostname.com/myaccount` translates to `http://myaccount.myhostname.com`

For this I use a `RewriteMap` and `RewriteRule` with `[P]` flag on. Everything works fine.

However I now need a persistent connection between the reverse proxy and the backend. I am well aware that keep-alive doesn't work with `RewriteRule`'s `[P]` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p - performance warning) therefore I tried to use `ProxyPass` and environment variable interpolation to do the work.
I got a `RewriteRule` that don't do nothing except saving the map result into an environment variable and then call the `ProxyPass` using this variable.

```
RewriteMap mymap prg:/path/to/my/map
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?.*$
RewriteCond ${mymap:%1} ^http://([^/]+/)$
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/?$ - [L,E=original:$1,E=rewritten:%1]

ProxyPassInterpolateEnv On
ProxyPassReverse /${original}/ http://${rewritten} interpolate
```

This result in the same behaviour as `RewriteRule` with `[P]`: the proxying is ok but don't uses http keep-alive.

I tried this with a hard-coded hostname instead of using `${rewritten}` (but keeping the `${original}`) and observed that it's the part that make Apache creating new connection instead of reusing an existing one.

This bug: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43308 is raising the same issue and propose a patch that may solve my problem.

However, I wanted to know if anyone had an idea to solve this in a different/better way.

Answer (score 0):

When using the [P] flag in a `RewriteRule` to proxy, you would normally be able to use the `ProxySet` directive to set the options normally configured via `ProxyPass`.

But in this case you do not have a specific proxy URL to configure. If you are *only* proxying user accounts, you could do something like:

```
ProxyPassMatch /\w+/ http://$1.myhostname.com/ keeplive=on
```

Although from your example it seems it's possible different domains are in use (hence the use of a `RewriteMap`).

Alternatively, another thought that just occurred,  it might work to use the following (untested):

```
<Proxy *>
    ProxySet keepalive=on
</Proxy>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already tried the ProxySet approach without much luck. Certainly due to the aforementioned bug. As you said, I can't use the ProxyPass directive due to the different domains.

Comment: You could try my first suggestion if you are just doing user accounts.